# Elasticsearch filter that returns items with maximum filter hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this elasticsearch items set.

```json
{
    "id": "1",
    "keyword": [
        "red",
        "blue"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "keyword": [
        "red",
        "yellow"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "keyword": [
        "yellow",
        "pink"
    ]
},
```

Field "keyword" is not tokenized and is indexed, so I can filter by [keyword:red] and I will have items "1" and "2" as a result, and if I filter by [keyword:red,yellow] I will have items "1", "2" and "3" as a result.

What I'm trying to achieve here is reach **only** the best results in terms of filtering. With this last filtered query [keyword:red,yellow], Items "1" and "3" matched only 1 of their keywords, and item "2" did it with both of them, so in that case, I'd like to get **only** item "2".

**EDIT**

This number must be dynamic, so should be the highest possible with results. If id "2" would have "black" instead "yellow", then the number would be 1, so all results would be valid.

What would be the strategy here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`bool/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause along with the `minimum_should_match` parameter

Try out this below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "keyword": "red"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "keyword": "yellow"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match":2
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66706691",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.9400072,
        "_source": {
          "id": "2",
          "keyword": [
            "red",
            "yellow"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: This number should be dynamic (I updated the question, sorry, this was not clear)